# How can I ask the user of any program for a value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, prompt

In JS it is called "prompt", but it is obviously not the same keyword in Swift. So my problem actually is that I want to ask the user of any program for a value. So how do I ask him and how do I safe that answer into a variable?

So this is how I would write it in Javascript for example when I want to use the input as a value for my calculations:

```
var n1 = prompt("give me a value");
var n2 = 3;
var i = 0;
var sum = 0;
while(i < n1){
   sum = sum + n2;
   i += 1;
}
document.write(sum)
```

And now I don't really know how to write the same in swift. I just want to ask the user for a value in "n1".

```
var n1 = 9;
var n2 = 5;
var i = 0;
var sum = 0;
while(i < n1){
   sum = sum + n2;
   i += 1;
}
print(sum)
```

How shall I write this in "var n1" ?

Comment: Show us what have you done. Many swift devs do not know Javascript, so it is better if you can do some research on it what it is called. But, fortunately I know and it is called UIAlertController in swift. Go ahead and search for it and you will get everything about it.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Command Line Tool.
Create New project - mac os tab - Command Line Tools.

You can ask user for input using readLine().

let a = readLine()

if  let input = a {
    print(input)
}

Comment: While this is correct notice that OP has tagged the question with iOS so then it can't be a command line tool